# Will enabling BitLocker remove EFS from already encrypted files in Windows 8.1?

Tags: bitlocker, efs

There are a few files on my Windows 8.1 machine that are encrypted using EFS - BitLocker is currently disabled.

I want to know whether BitLocker will look for, and remove EFS encryption from files if I enable it? Or will the EFS encryption remain on the individual files, in addition to the full disk encryption BitLocker will be providing?

Does anybody know if the EFS encryption will be removed from those files/folders that it is enabled for, and if it wasn't automatically removed could that cause a problem?

Comment: No; It won't.  EFS and Bitlocker are independent features within Windows.  Technically...EFS is a feature of NTFS not Windows.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't actually choose to encrypt any of the files that have been encrypted, it seems to be getting applied by the Windows 8.1 Mail App to attachments that have been sent to me.

As they are separate I should be fine to enable BitLocker over the top without problems